# Contracted indices can be interchanged?

Tags: tensors

I am trying to do some research in Lorentz transformations and I get a tensor of the form

$$M_{abcd}=\epsilon_{ab\mu \nu}\Lambda^\mu\hspace{0.1cm}_c\Lambda^\nu\hspace{0.1cm}_d$$
Where $\epsilon_{ab\mu \nu}$ is the totally antisymmetric (pseudo-)tensor of Levi-Civita. 
Is it posible to interchange contracted indices so that I can get
$$M_{abdc}=\epsilon_{ab\mu \nu}\Lambda^\mu\hspace{0.1cm}_d \Lambda^\nu\hspace{0.1cm}_c=-\epsilon_{ab \nu\mu}\Lambda^\mu\hspace{0.1cm}_d\Lambda^\nu\hspace{0.1cm}_c=-M_{abcd}$$. 
Also is posible to check if  $M_{abcd}=uM_{cdab}$ with $u=\pm 1$

Comment: Is this a question about the software _Mathematica_ or about the mathematics?

Comment: Note that if this were true then $2M_{abcd}=0$ so $M_{abcd}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

A Wolfram Language approach to verifying your identity is to give assumptions on your tensors:

```
$Assumptions = ϵ ∈ Arrays[{4,4,4,4}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1,2,3,4}]] && Λ ∈ Matrices[{4,4}];
```

And then to use [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce):

```
TensorReduce[TensorContract[TensorProduct[ϵ,Λ,Λ],{{3,5},{4,7}}]]
TensorReduce[-TensorContract[TensorProduct[ϵ,Λ,Λ],{{3,7},{4,5}}]]
```

> TensorContract[TensorProduct[ϵ,Λ,Λ],{{3,5},{4,7}}]

> TensorContract[TensorProduct[ϵ,Λ,Λ],{{3,5},{4,7}}]

Both expressions reduce to the same tensor.